# Javascript MutationObserver: How to Highlight edited DOM element?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am trying to detect when a value of an `<li>` changes and then add a class to the the li by adding a background color.

I have this switch:

```
mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
  switch(mutation.type) {
    case 'childList':
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
      console.log('childlist edited');
      break;
    case 'attributes':
      console.log('attr edited')
      break;
  }
});
```

but the color is not adding to the background. I am however getting loads of console logs like so:

> (66) childlist edited
>
> (2) childlist edited
>
> (14) childlist edited
>
> (81) childlist edited

This is what I want to happen:

1) when the value of the li changes, run a function

2) That function will clear all css from all li's and then add background-red to the li that was just edited.

```js
function onTimerElapsed() {
 var next = Math.floor(Math.random() * jQuery('#stuff ul li').length - 1);

 if (next === -1) {
  next = 0;

 }

 var nextLi = document.querySelectorAll('#stuff ul li')[next];

 var id = nextLi.attributes["id"].value;

 $('#' + id).text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1150));
 
 var targetNode = document.querySelector("#stuff ul");
 var observerOptions = {
   childList: true,
   attributes: true,
   subtree: true //Omit or set to false to observe only changes to the parent node.
 }

 var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
 observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
 }

 function callback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    switch(mutation.type) {
      case 'childList':
        console.log('childlist edited')
        break;
      case 'attributes':
        console.log('attr edited')
        break;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(onTimerElapsed, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Detect Dom change</h1>
<div id="stuff">
 <ul>
  <li class="total" id="t1">1453</li>
  <li class="total" id="t2">523</li>
  <li class="total" id="t3">54643</li>
  <li class="total" id="t4">2324</li>
  <li class="total" id="t5">56476</li>
  <li class="total" id="t6">3434</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/josz492m/"* Please update your question to put your runnable example ***in** the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) instead of just linking to it. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: What are you talking about, I added the code: The rest of it is just fiddling with the actually changing the dom for the demo only.

Comment: @ Mark - There's no call to be rude. I'm talking about putting your **runnable** example **in** the question, as I said above, rather than leaving it off-site. It makes it easier for people to help you, which surely is your goal?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How have I been rude? and the reason I added the JSFiddle link is because it requires additional libraries and most people ask for a jsfiddle link.

Comment: @ Mark - "What are you talking about" when someone politely asks you to do something and is clear about what it is, is rude. External libs aren't a problem, and people asking for jsFiddles are just out of date -- what they really want is a runnable example, which is best-provided (in 95% of cases) on-site.

Comment: I see the issue. I suppose "What are you talking about" could be seen as rude but I genuinely was asking "What are you talking about". Tone Faux Pas

Comment: @Mark I've added your code sample in the question to demonstrate that JSFiddle is not needed. As T.J. Crowder says, you can do that via the button that looks like `[<>]` (or a little page with `<>` in it). It even presents a UI similar to a fiddle. You can choose what external libraries to use on the left hand side - there are dropdowns for popular ones and you can include others by providing a link to a CDN copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MutationObserver callback takes a [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord), which has a `target` property that refers to the element in question. Use `target` instead of `this` to refer to the element whose attributes or subtree changed:

```
mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
  switch(mutation.type) {
    case 'childList':
      mutation.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      console.log('childlist edited');
      break;
    case 'attributes':
      console.log('attr edited')
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: `mutation.target` will be the element that the MutationObserver is attached to. Using `mutation.addedNodes` you can get the new nodes that were attached.

Comment: Thanks this solved it. Nice to see you found the link off site easy to get to.

Comment: @vlaz is right, addedNodes would be the prop to use for children.